# QGIS label spacing

Tags: qgis, labeling, maps

Wondering how to space out the road names on my QGIS map to make it look cleaner?

[image: QGIS Map Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the layer properties dialog and navigate to Labels -> Rendering there should be an option that reads "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels". This has usually helped me in the past.

However, I've still had times where the labels were still not cleaned up enough. I tend to store my data in PostGIS so in these cases I write a view which unions all the features based on road name. This combines all segments of the same road together into a single feature. It often cleans things up quite nicely.

A more labor-intensive method would be to do custom placement of labels. Some of the work can be done with a plugin such as "Layer to labeled layer". Search the plugin repository for several options.